# Customer is being charged for a Non-Renewing Subscription IAP without his consent

Tags: objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

A user signed up for my app via a non-renewing subscription that is validated with a remote server. My server processes the in app purchase fine & the user receives the content just fine.

However, the user is emailing me & saying that **every time he opens the app, he is charged without his consent.** He says that he does not tap any buttons but the UI i have developed for finishing in app purchases ("the processing screen") appears & his card is charged.

My server logs of his receipts confirm that he is charged multiple times, & his account on my server is reflected with this information. This happens even after he uninstalls & reinstalls the app.

Is this even possible for him to be charged without his consent ?

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Have you added any code in delegate class for In App Purchase?

Comment: This does not sound right. Are you using Apple's In-App purchase servers for transactions or some home grown thing? Every in-app purchase through apple requires users confirmation and password.